# Python - time complexity of binary search algorithm in nested list

Tags: python, time-complexity, complexity-theory, binary-search

I have a nested list of numbers, where I got n number of rows and columns and every number is increasing in every row and column.

For example:

```
A = [[19, 30, 31, 45, 57],
     [25, 32, 32, 51, 69],
     [33, 35, 38, 58, 78],
     [34, 49, 67, 84, 102],
     [44, 54, 73, 90, 115]]
```

I need to use binary search to find if an element is in the list and the time complexity in the worst case of the algorithm must be O(n).

I have this code:

```
def find(A, v):
    i = 0

    for row in A:
        num = binary_search(v, row, 0, len(row) - 1)
        if num != -1:
            return(i, num)
        i += 1

    return None


def binary_search(v, row, left, right):
    if left > right:
        return -1

    mid = (left + right) // 2

    if row[mid] == v:
        return mid

    elif row[mid] > v:
        return binary_search(v, row, left, mid - 1)

    elif row[mid] < v:
        return binary_search(v, row, mid + 1, right)
```

I think that this code has time complexity O(n log n), but I'm not really sure about that. So what is the real time complexity of this code?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the values are sorted columnwise? i.e `[19, 25, 33, 34, 44], [30, 32, 35, 49, 54], ...` are all sorted from least to greatest.

Comment: @Ajax1234 That's not relevant to what the OP asked. They asked us to do their homework by computing the time complexity of *that* algorithm. They did not ask how they can improve the time complexity or whether the code is correct.

Comment: @Bakuriu I would certainly say it is, and yes, I do think they are asking how to improve the algorithm, especially since they mention the requirement to keep the time complexity below `O(n)`.

Comment: @Ajax1234 " So what is the real time complexity of this code?"

Comment: your are right time complexity of this code is `O(n log n)` `O( log n )` for the `binary_search` function & `O ( n )` for the loop on **A array**

Comment: @Bakuriu There is no guarantee that the OP will not ask for an improvement later on (as often happens on SO). Thus, it is necessary to be as clear as possible, especially regarding the data and time complexity.

Comment: This is all I need to know, I just wanted to make sure if the code has the right time complexity or not :) I can try to improve the code by myself, so thank you very much.